# SQL Sorting Data into a Pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

Not sure if this is possible, but there might be a creative approach...

Given this data in SQL Server 2005:

AAA
AAA
BBB
BBB
CCC
CCC
DDD
DDD

How could I return a result set sorted in a pattern like this:

AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD

Comment: Do you have any other fields that could create this order?

Comment: there are no other fields, but i could certainly add them, what data to you recommend adding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your column were called "col", and your table were named "table", I would try something like this:

```
WITH Indexes AS (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col ORDER BY col) as __row,
    col
    FROM table)
SELECT col
FROM Indexes
ORDER BY __row, col;
```

Comment: +1: This is more general than my solution which works only for 2 copies.

Comment: +1 I'd never have thought of using "PARTITION BY col ORDER BY col"

Comment: Actually, it really doesn't matter what you order by, because all of the values are the same within any given partition.  I just chose col because it was convenient.  You could order by anything.

Comment: I just posted the exact same question, but for MYSQL. @DaveMarkle: would you have a solution for MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it works, but in Oracle I would try to create a view in which you use ROWNUM in the query of your view.

Then query the view and sort on:

- rownum modulo 2
- the string

I don't have my database at hand here to test this, but this tip might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql, assuming you have table T(a varchar); with the data you provided:

```
select @t:=a from T order by @t <> a;
```

it works :-)

Comment: Oops... just saw you need SQL Server 2005